# codemirror - get element class under cursor

Tags: javascript, class, codemirror

Is it possible get the classname from element where is cursor| located in editor content?

```
editor.on('cursorActivity', function(ed)
{
    // get current element classname (style) from codemirror editor when you move cursor| with keyboard
});
```

I have:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.CodeMirror-line>span>*', _detectTag);

function _detectTag()
{
    var classList = $(this).attr('class');

    console.log(classList);
}
```

It works, but it's not what I need because it's necessary to click with a mouse.

**For clarification:** https://jsfiddle.net/3tj1wv44/1/
(Click with mouse on element.. Is highlighted. Same highlighting i need when you move cursor in editor with keyboard.)

Any way to solve this is much appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why exactly are you trying to do this though? This may be an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), and there may be a [**better way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676) of reaching the end goal.

Comment: It doesn't matter how this could be done. I need to know the classname element when moving the cursor. Thank.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by finding the class that is hovered over though? I'm fairly sure that isn't possible, unless you make use of `:hover`.

Comment: but we talk about the codemirror editor cursor(!), not mouse pointer..